# ERROR 403 - FORBIDDEN

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, get

*Example URL:*

"example.com/MemberLogin?redirect=http://www.example.com/My-Account/Details"  **-> 403 Error**

"example.com/MemberLogin?redirect=My-Account/Details" **-> No Error**

"example.com/MemberLogin?" **-> No Error**

What is the reason for this?

**MemberLogin.php**

```
 <?php
   define("_VALID_PHP", true);
   require_once("/.../init.php");

   if ($user->logged_in)
       redirect_to("http://www.example.com/Yonlendirme.php?redirect=" . $_GET['redirect'] .      "");


   if (isset($_POST['doLogin']))
       : $result = $user->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

   /* Login Successful */
   if ($result)
       : redirect_to("http://www.example.com/Yonlendirme.php?redirect=" . $_GET['redirect']      . "" );
   endif;
   endif;
 ?>
```

**Yonlendirme.php**

```
 <?php if ($_GET['redirect'])
 {
     header('Location: ' . $_GET['redirect'] . '');
 }
 else
 {
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/My-Account');
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: `urlencode($_GET['redirect'])` it...

Comment: @LozCherone Thanks but it's not work

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, and still say it dont work? If so please show whats in the `redirect_to` function..

```
<?php
   define("_VALID_PHP", true);
   require_once("/.../init.php");

   if ($user->logged_in)
       redirect_to("http://www.example.com/Yonlendirme.php?redirect=".urlencode($_GET['redirect']));


   if (isset($_POST['doLogin']))
       : $result = $user->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

   /* Login Successful */
   if ($result)
       : redirect_to("http://www.example.com/Yonlendirme.php?redirect=".urlencode($_GET['redirect']));
   endif;
   endif;
?>
```

...

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['redirect']))
{
    exit(header('Location: ' . urldecode($_GET['redirect'])));
}
else
{
    exit(header('Location: http://www.example.com/My-Account'));
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, `MemberLogin?` now the error does not.. Only redirect page gives an error (Yonlendirme.php - 403 Error )

Comment: I checked.. I can not reach directly to this address: `http://www.example.com/Yonlendirme.php` Gives an error: Internal 500 error.. I do not understand why it gives error

Comment: have you got mod_rewrite enabled on your server?